# C ignoring the "Enter"-Key if input(integer) is empty

Tags: c

I was searching through the questions but I never found an answer for my problem.
I am having a problem, when you are waiting for an integer input with scanf, but before writing any integer or anything else you start spamming the "Enter"-Key, it will make all the time a newline.

I want just if you wait for an input but nothing is written and you press the "Enter"-key then it shouldn't make a newline, it should stay in the same line..

My code so far(only one part):

```
printf("\n> ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

(the choice variable is declared as an integer)

With this I'm clearing newline from the buffer but it is still jumping in the next line.. I also tried with a do-while but it still creates a newline when there is no input and you press the "Enter"-key.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: It is usually operating system specific. However, [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is returning the number of successfully scanned items, and you should test it! On Linux use [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Comment: Google for "ncurses"

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: I usually wanted to solve it without any additional libraries..
Hm I will just try it out with     fgets()

Comment: I got it working with     fgets()
I would like to vote but i still dont have enough reputation to vote comments ):

Comment: Use `while (scanf("%d", &choice) < 1);` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: @barak manos `while (scanf("%d", &choice) < 1);` would cause an infinite loop should user enter "ABC".

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you first use a function in C, you should *always read and fully understand* [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html). This explains why.

According to [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifier.

So your `d` conversion specification (the `d` is in `%d`) is executed by first skipping as much white-space as possible. That's how `fscanf` is documented to execute. If you want a different behaviour, then you'd have to write some extra/other code. I've *read and fully understood* [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), and even referred to it many times before (in answers to questions very similar to this one, might I add) so I can state that you probably meant to write something like this, in order to display your prompt similarly to how other consoles do:

```
int c;
do {
    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    c = getchar();
} while (isspace(c));

/* Check for EOF */
if (c == EOF) {
    /* XXX: Clean up resources before exiting
     * (or handling EOF however else you handle it) */
    exit(0);
}

/* Put the non-space character that terminated the loop back into stdin */
ungetc(c, stdin);

/* Check scanf success */
if (scanf("%d", &choice) == 1) {
    /* Do what you will with choice here */
}

/* Discard any remaining characters up to and including the first '\n' */
do {
    /* Some consider it poor style to put side-effects into condition expressions... */
    c = getchar();
} while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
```

P.S. If you were to *read and fully understand* [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) you might realise you could use this instead of that last loop: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();`